# How to merge the list in `defaultdict` using keys, but keep the list separate within that key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, defaultdict

I want to merge the list in `defaultdict` which has class (keys) and list-values from two different data/file.
I want to merge the list using the unique key but keep the list values separate.

**Input:**

`defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'1335': ['C', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'G'], '254': ['T', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'G']})`

`defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'1335': ['A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A'], '254': ['A', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'A']})`

**output:**

`defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'1335': ['C', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'G'], ['A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A'] , '254': ['T', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'G'], ['A', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'A']})`

Thanks,

Comment: Do both of the dicts have exactly the same keys? If not what's the desired output in that case?

Comment: Yes, most of the keys will be same, but I think there might be instances in other data files where some keys will be unique to each data. In that case I would like to merge as well but it will have list only from one data. Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the new dictionary's value to be a list of lists.

You can create a new `defaultdict` of lists, and append the list value from each dictionary:

```
input_dicts = [dict1, dict2]

result = defaultdict(list)

for to_merge in input_dicts:
    for key, value in to_merge.items():
        result[key].append(value)
```

Comment: I will check this. If I have lots of dictionaries, do you think it's also possible to do `merged_dict = defaultdict(dict1, dict2)` ? and then later run the `for-loop`, like `for merged_dict:` Thanks

Comment: No, duplicate keys aren't allowed, so it'll only keep the most recent value

Comment: So, your solution works for 2 different default dict. What if I want to do it with 3 or more `defaultdict`. My actual data will have several `defaultdicts`

Comment: I've put the input dictionaries in a list. You can make the list as long as you need.

Comment: Also, I am assuming, it would merge the list if there are any unique keys that belong to only one `default dict`, something like `outer` or `inner` in pandas.